# Should this question have been closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, vote-to-reopen

[Distributed Domain Driven Design Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256946/distributed-domain-driven-design-resources)

4 people upvoted it in 2 hours. It asked a question that required a concrete answer, and that's what it received. I think it was wrong to close this.

Answer (score 13):

> This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; **this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.**

Until this changes, the answer is **yes**.

Answer (score 5):

The "question" actually contains several questions. This alone make it not a good fit for Q&A format. The fact that the question is interesting for X people does not change this. The accepted answer actually provides links to podcasts, books and other resources. While useful, it does not answer any question. You said 'I'm not looking for answers to the above questions, just pointing in the direction of resources that will answer this and simmilar questions.' which means exactly that it's not a good fit for a Q&A format, as the point of SO is not to build a list with links to resources, which can be unavailable in any given time.